# Nested serializer with optional field raising KeyError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers, first one (a bit simplified):

```
class FilterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    brand = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=org_models.Brand.objects, many=False,
        error_messages={'does_not_exist': org_consts.BRAND_NOT_EXIST}
    )

    country = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=org_models.Country.objects, many=False,
        error_messages={'does_not_exist': org_consts.COUNTRY_NOT_EXIST}
    )

    level = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=org_models.Level.objects, many=False, required=False,
        error_messages={'does_not_exist': org_consts.DISTRICT_NOT_EXIST}
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = ('brand', 'country', 'level')
```

and second:

```
class PeopleReportSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    filters = FilterSerializer(many=True)
    start_date = serializers.DateField(required=False)
    end_date = serializers.DateField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('filters', 'start_date', 'end_date')

    def validate(self, data):
        """Check if end_date occurs after start_date.
        """
        if data.get('start_date') and data.get('end_date'):
            if data['start_date'] > data['end_date']:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(constants.INVALID_START_DATE)
        return data
```

I've removed some fields for clarity.
So basically all I want from this serializer is validation if objects with posted ID exist in the database. On GET I would like it to return some data depending on request.user but that's another case.

So now in my view I'm doing something like this:

```
class PeopleReportView(ReportsPermissionMixin, views.APIView):
    serializer_class = PeopleReportSerializer
    task = staticmethod(people_report)  # celery task, creates reports

    def get(self, request):
        # TODO: depending on request.user return initial data such as:
        # country / brand / district and so on
        return Response()

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            task = self.task.apply_async(kwargs=serializer.data)
            return Response({'task_id': task.id})
```

my problem is that when I post data without `level` field (which is NOT a required field) I get `KeyError: 'level'`. <s>`FilterSerializer` works fine, but when it's nested I'm getting this error.</s> *Apparently I was wrong*, my test wasn't testing `data` property, only `is_valid` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is a `Field` it doesn't work the same way when initialized with `required=False`. Just like Remi wrote the only way that is supported in current version of DRF (3.5.X) for read/write fields is to `allow_null` on these fields (besides using some strange workarounds).

API has to send an empty field, and in object representation *i.e.* `Serializer.data` this fields will have a None value. Since in my case I mustn't had None values I modified `Serialzier.to_representation` method like so:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
        """Excludes fields with None value from representation
        """
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        return {field: value for (field, value) in ret.items()
                if value is not None}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `allow_null` flag instead:

```
 level = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    queryset=org_models.Level.objects, many=False, allow_null=True,
    error_messages={'does_not_exist': org_consts.DISTRICT_NOT_EXIST}
)
```

instead of:

```
 level = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    queryset=org_models.Level.objects, many=False, required=False,
    error_messages={'does_not_exist': org_consts.DISTRICT_NOT_EXIST}
)
```

See [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) for more information